# em R, dec="," não funciona em read.csv2

Tags: r, csv

Boa tarde...
Estou tentando importar csv onde os decimais estão separados por ponto... ou seja algo assim 2.5

Eu quero que na hora de importar ele apareça com virgula, algo tipo assim, 2,5

```
 uo_14<- read.csv2("csv\\uo_2014.csv", as.is = FALSE , header = TRUE, 
                     sep = ",", dec=",", encoding='UTF-8' )


 uo_14
    nome   valor1  valor 2
    nome1   3.5      3.6
    nome2   5.4      1.7
```

Não sei qual é problema!

Comment: Acho que vc nao pode usar o mesmo separador de colunas e de casas decimais

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se o objetivo for somente mudar a forma como o output do R apresenta o separador decimal, você pode usar:

```
options(OutDec = ",")
```

Veja a descrição da opção `Outdec` na help page da função `options` (`?options`) para mais informações.

Além disso, se o seu arquivo csv usa ponto como separador decimal, então você deveria usar `dec = "."` na função `read.csv2`:

```
uo_14 <- read.csv2("csv\\uo_2014.csv", as.is = FALSE, header = TRUE, 
                 sep = ",", dec = ".", encoding='UTF-8')
```